# Inherit position absolute

Tags: html, css

```css
.Wrap
{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  border:2px solid #000;
 }
.container
{
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:100px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:grey;
  }
.box
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:15px;
```

```html
<div class="Wrap">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="box">
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Is it possible that `class="box"` was child only `class="container"`? I mean that inherit position absolute from "container" but no from "Wrap".

Comment: Do you want the red box placed inside gray box?

Comment: Yes, give container `position: relative;`

Comment: `.box` position will be based from the first (non-statically) positioned parent element. Since both `.container` and `.Wrap` are not positioned (that is, have their default `position: static;`) it will probably be the `body` that `.box` position relates to.

Comment: yes, red box inside grey, but not use position relative

Comment: If you **really need** absolute positioning on `.box` and you want the position to be based on `.container` there's no other way than making `.container` either `position: absolute;`, `position: relative;` or `position: fixed;`. Ofc you can always have `.box` position based on e.g. `.Wrap` as well, but that would require a recalculation of `.box` `top`and `left` properties each time you reposition `.container`. Usually you want to avoid that kind of dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To position the `box` relative to the `container` you either set `position: relative;` on the `container`, or, as in below sample, remove the `left`/`top` on the `box`

Be aware that removing the `left`/`top` can give some unpredictable result, as you give the browser the control to interpret how to position the `box`.

```css
.Wrap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If he still needs "positioning" `.box`, he can always go with margins instead of `top` and `left`.

Comment: @connexo Yes, that is very true, though it still can give unpredictable result from where to start, as it will be browser dependent